# rickshaw.js displaying additional data in tooltips

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, rickshaw

I have a richshaw plot with tooltips enabled (Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail). I need to display more information in it, not just series y values. Can it be accomplished with Richshaw or do I have to use the underlying d3 functions.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response. Yes you can actually render whatever you want inside rickshaw tooltips with Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail .

Lets say for example that you have a function that requires as inputs *series*, *x* and *y* and lets assume that we have another array with the same length as x array called *dates*:

```
var hoverDetail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({
  graph: graph,
  formatter: function(series, x, y) {
    var content = '<span class="graph-dates">'+dates[x]+'</span><br><span class="graph-price">'+series.name+": "+currency+parseInt(y) +'</span>';
    return content;
  }
});
```

The code renders on the hover details a date for the chosen x point and the price for that date.

In the [documentation](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/) of rickshaw graph you can find further information.

[Here](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/formatter.html) is the actual example by rickshaw.